# File Read : Getting partial Output

Tags: java, file, filestream

i have the following code to retrive the data from my file. When i execute the code i come to know it's giving only 50% of the lines from the total lines. Why it's happening ?

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int count = 1;
    try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("C:/FaceProv.log");
            DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(fileInput);
            InputStreamReader inputStr = new InputStreamReader(dataInput);
            BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(inputStr);

                while(bufRead.readLine() != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Count "+count+" : "+bufRead.readLine());
                    count++;

                }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fix would be String line; while ((line=bufRead.readLine()) != null), remove second readline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reading the lines twice:

```
while(bufRead.readLine() != null) /// HERE
{
     System.out.println("Count "+count+" : "+bufRead.readLine()); // AND HERE
     count++;

}
```

but you only count them once. So you're actually reading the whole file, but counting only half of the lines.

Change it to:

```
String line;
while((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println("Count "+count+" : " + line);
     count++;
}
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thank you. But i'm getting some empty lines in the console. For example : In the input line total lines are 100 i'm getting 120 or 125 lines.

Comment: @Mayilarun are you sure? it's pretty much impossible with the code you've shown us.

Comment: @Mayilarun maybe check the file encoding and/or if there's some spurious cr-lf at the end of the line

Comment: yeah it's happening. And one more issue is a single line in the input file is coming as 2 line in the console. Whether it's because of the buffer size anything like that??

Comment: How i can find the encoding of the file? Through program i can able to track that??

Comment: @Mayilarun you can try opening it in a browser to see if there are any funky characters, and then keep changing the encoding until they disappear

Comment: @Mayilarun - You're not removing the newlines from the end of the lines read from the file, then using `System.out.println()` which is adding another newline; this is the source of your blank lines in the console. Use `System.out.print()` instead. As for your count being "off" ... it's not, as far as how you have it defined. `readLine()` is reading a line as defined in the docs (see the javadoc for `BufferedReader.readline()`) and you're counting each one.

Comment: @BrianRoach he doesn't have to remove them. readLine() strips them off automatically, from da doc `Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached`

Comment: @Brain Roach : Still i'm getting some extra lines. Kindly check my 2 comment.

Comment: @soulcheck : If the line has a extra white space in the last then it will consider that a new line??

Comment: @soulcheck - doh! Thanks, I so rarely use `readLine` I forgot it does that. The latter part of the comment still stands though.

Answer (score 4):

Because

```
while(bufRead.readLine() != null)
```

discards the line it just read.

```
String myLine = null;
while ((myLine = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Count "+count+" : " + myLine);
    ...
```